# Using object literal notation to set a property's value in terms of another property

Tags: javascript

I encounter an error in the following code because of the way I try to define the 'scanning' property on my reader object.

```
app.controller("turingController", ["$scope", function($scope) {



    $scope.cellArray = []; 

    for( var i=0; i<=999; i++) {

        $scope.cellArray[i] = {

            index: i,

            content: "B",

        };

    };


    $scope.reader = {

        location: 500,

        state: "q1",

        scanning: $scope.cellArray[$scope.reader.location].content
    };

}]);
```

But if I don't use object literal notation to define the 'scanning' property, it works fine. Like this:

```
$scope.reader = {

    location: 500,

    state: "q1",

    };

$scope.reader.scanning = $scope.cellArray[$scope.reader.location].content
```

I realize that I've solved the problem, but I'm still wondering why it doesn't work in the first code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are defining `$scope.reader` in the first example, you are also calling `$scope.reader` (actually `$scope.reader.location`) within the definition.  At the point you call `$scope.reader.location` you have not finished defining `$scope.reader`.  So it gets confused...

In the second method, you first define the `$scope.reader` object, then add a new property (`scanning`) to it, setting the value based in part on `$scope.reader`.  This is fine since the `$scope.reader` object now exists

Answer (score 1):

At the point in which you construct the object literal for `$scope.reader`, you haven't actually defined `$scope.reader` yet — you're trying to reference a variable that does not exist yet.

However, by setting it afterwards, in your new code, `$scope.reader` has been set, so you can reference it without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is javascript problem, not really angularjs. `location` doesn't exist until the following line `$scope.reader = {};` is finished.

It is something along this line:

```
var A = 100;
var B = A = B; 

//What is the value of B? 
//Does (B = A) execute first, so B = 100? 
//Does (A = B) execute first, so B = undefined?

//answer, B is undefined.

//this is analogy to your case
// var R.A = 100 never happens until R = {} is finished.
// so B = A is undefined
var R = {
  A: 100,
  B: A
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression is evaluated prior to assignment.  You statement is like this:

```
var temp = {
    location: 500,
    state: "q1",
    scanning: $scope.cellArray[$scope.reader.location].content
};
$scope.reader = temp;
```

So when the property is being assigned a value, `$scope.reader` has not yet been set.